# How do I get the caret to line up with text

Tags: html, css

I have text and then a carat which drops down the text but for some reason can not get the caret to vertically align with the text despite my efforts.

Jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nCP9J/5/

HTML:

```
<div id ="hiddensubmit" class = "dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" onclick="document.formSearch.submit()" style="top:55px; font-size:20px;">
<a href="#" id="drop" class ="dropdownsearch">Stuff&nbsp;<span class = "searchcaret" style="display:inline;line-height:66px;vertical-align:middle;"></span></a></div>
```

CSS:

```
.dropdown-toggle {
  *margin-bottom: -3px;
}
.searchcaret {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  line-height:100px;
  padding: 10px 0px 0px 0px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  border-top: 4px solid #000000;
  border-right: 4px solid transparent;
  border-left: 4px solid transparent;
  content: "";
  opacity: 0.3;
  color: #5A5A5A;
  filter: alpha(opacity=30);
```

position:absolute; top:10px;
    }

Comment: I believe that's because you're creating it out of a border. The easiest, but not the best way to align it, is to set position:relative, then just use top: to bring it down.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/amitfts/nCP9J/13/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your inline CSS for the caret span, change:

```
<a href="#" id="drop" class ="dropdownsearch">Stuff&nbsp;<span class = "searchcaret" style="display:inline;line-height:66px;vertical-align:middle;"></span></a>
```

to:

```
<a href="#" id="drop" class ="dropdownsearch">Stuff&nbsp;<span class = "searchcaret" style="display:inline-block;line-height:66px;vertical-align:middle;"></span></a>
```

you need to change that for any vertical aligning. Then move the padding in the CSS to tweak it exactly how you want.

Answer (score 1):

Change this:

```
<a href="#" id="drop" class ="dropdownsearch">Stuff&nbsp;<span class = "searchcaret" style="display:inline;line-height:66px;vertical-align:middle;"></span></a></div>​
```

To this:

```
<a href="#" id="drop" class ="dropdownsearch">Stuff&nbsp;<span class = "searchcaret"></span></a></div>​
```

It was mainly the `display:inline` that did it.